# Best way to backup/clone a hard drive in Mac OS X 10.10 (Yosemite)

Tags: macos, hard-drive, mac, backup, clone

I have a MacBook Pro which I use for work. I have a lot of software installed and configured which I do not want to have to re-install/configure in the event my MacBook Pro is stolen or damaged.

I’d like to somehow “clone” the drive in a way that if something were to happen I could just go buy a new MacBook Pro, use the clone program to load my HD image and instantly be back where I was before the old computer broke or got stolen.

I know there is a time machine backup built into Mac OS X but that is only good for backing up individual files like documents or pictures - which I do not care about. I want to be able to get back all my installed apps with their custom configurations so I don't lose time from working - hence the HD clone - image idea.

What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

[SuperDuper!](http://www.shirt-pocket.com/SuperDuper/SuperDuperDescription.html) does just that, and I—like you—prefer an external USB drive ready to roll in the event of a disaster.